# DI dotnet/C#: Resolve objects with (different) strings in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, constructor, factory

I have a .Net Console Application using Configuration, DependencyInjection and Hosting, where I need to create several Objects, where each object is different depending on a passed string.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .Build();

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IOtherService, OtherService>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IMyObject, MyObject>();
        ...


public class MyObject : IMyObject
{
    public string _aString {get; set;}

    public MyObject(string aString)
    {
        _aString = aString;
    }
}


public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private IMyObject _objectA;
    private IMyObject _objectB;
    private readonly IOtherService _otherService;
    private readonly IOptions<FilePaths> _filePaths;

    public MyService(IOtherService otherService, IOptions<FilePaths> filePaths)
    {
        _otherService = otherService;
        // file path options contains 2 different file path strings
        _filePaths = filePaths;
    }

    public void WorkWithObjects()
    {
        // Instantiate Objects depending on File Path Strings
        // Do some work with my objects here
    }
}
```

Each string is a file path which defines the object, but I abstracted the behaviour in above example.

What is the best way to go about this? Is my design correct?
I did some research and tried to:

- Instantiate Objects in MyService directly (this is bad, because it violates DI)
- Create a MyObjectFactory as Service and directly instantiate Objects there (but now I need to change the Factory implementation if I was to change the MyObject implementation, so this also violates DI ?)
- Work with ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance() but I could not find a way to pass a string parameter
- take out the string parameter from the object constructor and put it into a method, which I call upon instantiating the object (but this seems like it would not be very clean)

Comment: You don't need a factory - you can configure the container to do all the heavy lifting: for examples see [here](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/07/27/diwithoptions/) or for an alternative approach [here](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/08/16/diwithconfiguration/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am already using the Options pattern, but I need several instances of the object each one different depending on the passed string. As far as I am concerned the Options Pattern solely doesnt solve my problem, because how do I specify which string within the configuration/options class it should be using upon creating an instance of MyObject.

Comment: "Instantiate Objects in MyService directly (this is bad, because it violates DI)". Whether this is bad completely depends on the role that object plays in the application. If `MyObject` is a [Volatile Dependency](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1/137), a typing a hard dependency on it would violate the DIP. But if it's not volatile, there's no harm in taking a hard dependency and newing it by hand.

Comment: "Work with ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance() but I could not find a way to pass a string parameter". I'm not saying that using `ActivatorUtilities` is the right answer (I don't know), but this code should allow you to create a `MyObject`: `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyObject>(provider, "someString")`.

Comment: "take out the string parameter from the object constructor and put it into a method, which I call upon instantiating the object (but this seems like it would not be very clean)". This could be a solution if the string is a runtime value. See [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/) for instance.

Comment: @Steven thank you very much for your input! I had no idea about the concept of volatility and i am currently looking it. Thanks for hinting me in this direction.
In regards to Activator.Ultities: I tried this before and I got the error that no suitable constructor was found.
At this point the string is no runtime value so I did not want to implement it is it were one. I also explored this option before. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to register MyObject in DI container: `serviceCollection.AddTransient<IMyObject, MyObject>();` as you are planning to have multiple 'MyObject' instances based on configuration. I assume that you can have multiple file paths in the configuration.

Introducing separate `IMyObjectsFactory` interface is perfectly fine and doesn't violate any rule. The only responsibility of the Factory will be to create instances of `IMyObject`. Changing factory implementation when `IMyObject` implementation is changed is perfectly fine. You abstract creation of `MyObject` to factory.

```
public interface IMyObjectsFactory
{
    IEnumerable<IMyObject> Create();
}

public class MyObjectFactory : IMyObjectsFactory
{
    private readonly IOptions<FilePaths> _filePaths;

    public MyObjectFactory(IOptions<FilePaths> filePaths)
    {
         _filePaths = filePaths;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IMyObject> Create()
    {
        foreach(var path in _filePaths.Value.Paths)
        {
            yield return new MyObject(path)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would it be fine to instantiate a concrete object of MyObject within the factory by passing the string as argument to the factory-method? I would use the Options Pattern within MyService and call the Create(_filePaths.Value.AFilePath) method which returns an IMyObject.

Comment: Of course, if you want to have that logic in Service , you can change the interface to IMyObjectFactory with following signature: IMyObject Create(string path). I am just curious whether you need _filePaths to any other action? Maybe it will be better to delegate creation of objects to separate factory as I suggested? Then service would need to operate on already created IMyObjects and it doesn't care how they're created

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for explaining in depth! If you don't mind I have some follow up questions. Let´s say I have 2 file paths as properties _filePaths.Value.PathA and _filePaths.Value.PathB and not a list of paths. Would the correct way to instantiate each MyObject with 2 seperate factory methods? CreateA() and CreateB() where each method gets the corresponding file path from the options class? Furthermore, MyService needs to be able to create MyObjects, where the constructor of MyObjects is parameterelss. With the factory pattern I would add another method called Create()?

Comment: something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EZ48Ik

Comment: It depends.. How many paths do you plan to have in the future? why do you want to have PathA and PathB instead of array? If you want to have 100 different paths in the future, your solution won't be scalable at all, you would have to create 100 methods in the factory like CreateA(), CreateB(), ... CreateZ(). If you have one common interface with common behaviour it becomes easy. What will you do later on with MyObject?

Comment: those are valid design concerns. thank you very much.